# Which code is potentially sensitive to environment (variables)?

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables

I have some (legacy) code here that seem to call `setenv` on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (with a value not known at compile time, actually it will be got from the command line), now I have to port it to windows. My suspicion is that `setenv` is done for historical reason only and that it has no actual effect anymore and I want to confirm that.

So my approach would be to review all uses of the environment and see if there's any one that would be affected by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or any else). So I figure that unless the `environ` variable or certain functions are called the code would be insensitive to the environment (either directly, indirectly or in subsequent code).

The functions that I've identified (as candidates) are:

- `getenv`
- `exec*`
- `popen`
- `system`
- `dlopen` and friends
- time functions that relies on the `TZ` variable only
- functions thats locale dependent and only retrieves the current locale

The `getenv` is included for obvious reasons as the subsequent code would probably depend on the value of the environment variable. `exec*`, `popen` and `system` are included because first the linking of the (child) program may be affected by the environment, but also the (child) program itself may be dependent on environment, `dlopen` I think will search the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the library (also here it's possible that the linked library itself accesses the environment during initialization or at a later point). The rest is because I'm aware that `TZ` and locale is being used at a lot of places in the standard libraries.

Have I missed some function or some other case where code may depend on the environment? Of course I realize that this is affected by the libraries that are loaded, but as far as I see there's only "standard" libraries loaded plus `libsqlite3` (plus `libpthread`, `libdl` and `libm`). I guess that SQLite3 may be sensitive to some environment variables, but is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` one of them?

For the record this time the program doesn't seem to include `exec*` or `dlopen`, but I include them because in another case they might.

Comment: dlopen makes me wonder if your application specific libraries are opened from LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The way i would proceed is to look at a installation and check the paths that are used in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Check all locations that is pointed by the application and libraries present in them.

Comment: @Pradheep I'm afraid that's not feasible. The value that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is being set to is not known at compile time.

Comment: why not print it out to any of your logs and check the paths or load the program in gdb which is much easier and check the value when it sets

Comment: Numeric formatting is dependent on locale.  Time, date, money formatting are dependent on locale.  Some collation (sorting) algorithms are dependent on locale.  Character classification is dependent on locale (digits, upper, lower, etc).  Most of that is covered by the standard C library (money formatting doesn't have a standard C function for the task, but the necessary information is stored in the locale information).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, that's why I included them in general. What I hope is that these functions are not dependent on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as well.

Comment: @Pradheep There's two problems with that approach. First of all the value set to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is dependent on the command line arguments so I can't deduce the value that way. Second checking reading of the `environ` variable would require a test case with quite high coverage which I don't have.

Comment: You could try simply setting (extending) `PATH` on Windows instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The `PATH` is considered as part of the [DLL Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Please post the related code.   getting and/or setting the environment is not 'legacy' but rather something that often needs to be done on-the-fly.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm not going to post 400k lines of proprietary code here.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the documentation for each function.  That for [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) clearly states that it uses `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as a search list to locate shared libraries.

It seems a rather clumsy way of forcing a specific library to be loaded when you can specify a path as an argument to `dlopen` in any case.

Other than that it is a value used by the GNU linker `ld` to locate *static* libraries. So less likely but possible is that it is used by your application because it launches the linker or some other process that uses `dlopen`, which it may do via `exec`, `popen`, or `system` for example.  Given that your code has all of these functions it is quite clearly launching some external process.

Comment: There are a lot of valid use cases for LD_LIBRARY_PATH when you want to force loading a specific library, e.g. anytime the `dlopen` call is not under your control such as when it's in a third party library or when it's in a separate process.

Comment: Checking the documentation was a good idea. I ran `zgrep` on the man pages and also found the `uselib` function. However it would miss the cases `getenv` and the functions for launching other programs which are potential ways to be dependent on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I think your question is answered; you'd need to analyse the code to determine why it was doing this.  Without seeing the code, I would guess that `getenv()` is used to get the current `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it is pre-pended or appended with some application specific path, and then set with `setenv()` before calling `dlopen()`.  The way in which `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is modified I think will be informative.  You seem to be looking for something at the system level, and I think this is entirely application specific.  You chose not to post any code, so we are left to guess.